# Is it possible to insert C# DateTime to SQL Server smalldatetime without rounding?

Tags: c#-4.0

While I am trying to insert `C# DateTime to Sql Server smalldatetime` column, it is always rounding to the next day. For e.g. I have a

`DateTime dt = '4/30/2014 11:59:59 PM'`,

this date is inserted as `'2014-05-01 00:00:00' in SQL SERVER`.

Is it possible to insert exact DateTime from C# to Sql Server without changing schema in the database.

-TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

A `smalldatetime` value can represent time down to the precision of one minute. The seconds will always be rounded to the closest minute.

Reference: [Date and Time (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo9bd1cc5b-227b-4032-95d6-7581ddcc9924.aspx)

---

Note: If you use a `datetime` value instead, the time will also be rounded, but from a precision of 1/10000 second in the `System.DateTime` value to the closest 1/300 second.

Comment: Thank you. Reference is helpful.